# Wordpress not outputting post in <p> tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress-theming, wordpress

So I'm using a custom loop to output a custom post type on some pages.

It works just fine, grabs the content etc, but it doesn't wrap the paragraphs in p tags.
I'm relatively new to WP, being as though I've just done front end stuff before, so forgive me if I'm making an elementary mistake here.

```
<div class="home-grid-1">
            <?php 
                query_posts(array( 
                    'post_type' => 'Headerhome',
                    'showposts' => 1 
                ) );  
            ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>

    </div> <!-- end home-grid-1 -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `echo get_the_content()`, which often does not have filters applied to it, use `the_content()` which will automatically echo the post content, with filters applied.

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    the_content();
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter you need is a transformer of double-line-breaks to `<p>` and `</p>`. It's called wpaup and is explained [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)

Comment: That's not working for me, I tried

<div class="home-grid-1">
    <?php 
        query_posts(array( 
            'post_type' => 'Headerhome',
            'showposts' => 1 
        ) );  
    ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      
    <?php $content = get_the_content(); ?>
    
    <?php
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
?>
    
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
  
  </div> <!-- end home-grid-1 -->

Still doesn't wrap in <p> tags, in fact it doesn't show up at all

Comment: I've edited my answer. Take a look at the first suggestion now.